# What is Write Back?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, xmla

When I process a cube in SSMS and script to XMLA, I notice the following element:

```
<WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
```

What is the writeback table creation feature, and what does it mean for SSAS to `UseExisting`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WritebackTableCreation Element (XMLA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187172.aspx):

> Determines whether a writeback table is created during the Process
>   operation...
>
> **UseExisting** Use the existing writeback table, if one already exists. If one does not exist, an error occurs.

Also on [Specifying Processing Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175594.aspx):

> **Writeback Table Options**   If writeback is enabled in the Analysis
>   Services project, this setting defines how writeback is handled....

For more details, see [Enabling and Securing Data Entry with Analysis Services Writeback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg567303.aspx):

> Why would you want to write data back to Analysis Services rather than
>   the relational database that provides the raw data? One reason is
>   latency. When you write data back to a relational database, users have
>   to wait until the cube is processed before the latest data becomes
>   available in their reports. However, when you enable writeback, users
>   can submit data straight into the cube in the current session, making
>   it instantly visible to other users of the Analysis Services database

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post, describes writeback and why it would create a table (or use an  existing table):

http://bimatters1403.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/ssas-2008-molap-writeback/